# Let firefox 57 load tabs in the background

Tags: firefox

How do I get firefox 57 to load tabs immediately, even if the tab opens in the background? (I don't want to switch to the tab, but it should still load).

I normally open links in the background by using the middle mouse button.

I found this: but the description is wrong: This controls loading on startup.
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/allow-firefox-load-multiple-tabs-background

Comment: I thought that was how all browsers worked, opening a link in a new tab (background or foreground) starts loading it, Chromium still does that, firefox did last I used it. Did an update change that? Does a new empty/fresh profile change it?

Comment: Yes, it changed in the Quantum update(V 57).

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Answers should really be in an answer, not a comment (there was an employee/moderator on one site that really didn't like them & strangely deleted tons of comments...) but it's the wrong answer anyway, the Q says it doesn't work